# Android Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My activity using and extending preferences activity as

```
SettingsUser extends PreferenceActivity
```

I am using preferenceScreen XML to design my shared Preference and adding it in my activity as

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mypreferences);
```

For getting my shared preferences I am doing

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Now I want to add `onClick` listener on my shared preference, I see there is a method called `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` but not `onClickListener`, anyone can guide how to handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
Preference infoPreference = findPreference(key);
infoPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great and thanks for nice ans . want to extend more using this method you can get specific Click Listener on specific Preference you can get all component of preference screen , like right now I am getting my ListPreference to do some action when it clicked  .